# How to get accuracy with splines

Tags: r, mgcv

I am using the `mgcv` package in R in order to predict bankruptcy.
The following dataset is used https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Taiwanese+Bankruptcy+Prediction

However, I can not figure out how to use the `mgcv` package to predict bankruptcies with splines.
My dependent variable (whether a company is bankrupt) is binary. I am trying to make a multidimensional regression where I use the independent variables to predict bankruptcy.

Besides that, I do not clearly see the point of using a splines method when my dependent variable is binary. Could someone explain to me why it might be useful to uses splines in this case?

Comment: Its worth doing a quick web search of "bankruptcy prediction additive models" as there are a bunch -- this will both give a bit of domain knowledge while showing how models are formulated. (some examples are  https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/asmb.658 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.6081 which might be interesting)

Comment: You are smoothing the predictors not the outcome. Consider, the case with a binary outcome, bankruptcy, and one predictor, say cash in bank. Too much or too little cash in bank can be an indicator of poor company performance. So we may expect a non-linear effect, for example a U shape. We can try to model this by adding a polynomial term (cash + cash^2) as our predictors. Or instead we can use gams to create the input matrix (as an alternative to the polynomial input)

Answer (score 3):

if you have a binary dependent variable, then I guess you will use logistic regression, which assumes the log odds are linear combination of the inputs.
using mgcv, the assumption is extended to a smooth (non linear) combination of the inputs.
The splines allow you to model the relationship between a given input and the log odds as non linear- eg perhaps impact of liability/total assets suddenly shoots up after reaching 50% liability/total assets.